# multivariate distributions bounded on [0,1] where parameters can be solved for from known mode

Tags: probability, distributions, multivariate-analysis, dirichlet-distribution

I need some kind of multivariate distribution which has the following properties

- support is $x_1,$ $x_2$, ..., $x_K$ where all $x_i \in [0,1]$
- Though not required it is true that elements of the support will sum to 1. $\sum x_i=1$
- the parameters of the distribution can be solved for if the mode is known. the parameters need not be unique to the mode but they must give the desired mode
- there are no other "peaks" in the distribution other than the mode

I tried doing this with the a Dirchlet distribution but it seems that this doesn't really work for all modes as I need it to. In particular if one of the components of the mode is zero I get odd results such as negative and zero values for the parameters of the Dirichlet distribution.

Is there some other distribution I could use? A way I can modify an existing distribution perhaps?

edit: I may have been solving for the parameters of the parameters of the Dirichlet distribution incorrectly. I used $x_i=\frac{\alpha_i-1}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^K{\alpha_n}-K}$ to create a system of linear equations by multiplying both sides by $\sum\limits_{n=0}^K{\alpha_n}-K$ for each $i$. I then solved this using the python module numpy's numpy.linalg.solve which uses linear algebra to solve large systems quickly.

Comment: There is an apparent inconsistency in this question: it appears to ask for families of unimodal distributions in which all possible modes can occur. That is true of the Dirichlet, so "doesn't really work" seems to express some error of calculation on your part rather than an inherent limitation. Are you therefore really just asking how to find a set of Dirichlet parameters to realize any given mode?

Comment: Perhaps I am solving for the parameters incorrectly. I will explain I how I solved for them. I found on wikipedia that the mode for a Dirchlet distribution was (alpha-1)/(a0-K) where alpha is the parameter vector, a0 is the sum of elements in alpha and K is the size of alpha. I used this to construct a system of linear equations and then used a linear algebra package in python to solve for the different values. The definition on wikipedia said that this mode was true for all a_i greater than 1 but I got things less than 1 in my answer.

Comment: Let the intended mode be $(x_1,\ldots,x_K)$ with $x_1+\cdots+x_K=1$. Pick any positive number $N$ and set $\alpha_i=Nx_i+1\ge 1$ for the parameters. Because $\sum_i\alpha_i-K=\sum_i(Nx_i+1)-K=N\sum_i x_i+(K-K)=N,$ the mode of a Dirichlet$(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_K)$ distribution has components $(\alpha_i-1)/(\sum_i\alpha_i-K)=(Nx_i+1-1)/N=x_i$.

Comment: RE the edit: clearly there is no unique solution. Solutions are parameterized by $N$. Thus you are much better off doing a little math yourself than using Python to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank You! This seems to be preforming very well and just as I would expect! Apprently the system I was using was choosing a bad free variable for me as a solution to the system. This is a lot easier to program with too! If you answer I will mark this as the solution.